# Hosting a Wordpress blog as a sub folder from a S3 website

Tags: subdomains, mod-rewrite, amazon

I have a website set up for my organisation under `www.mycompany.com` *(running on Amazon S3)*.  I also have a Wordpress blog set up under `blog.mycompany.com` *(running on a separate LAMP server)*.

For SEO purposes, our marketing department has asked to set up `www.mycompany.com/blog` to go to our blog main page.

Our website is currently hosted on an Amazon S3 bucket, behind Amazon Cloudfront.  I have managed to set up S3/CloudFront redirections successfully so that a basic redirection happens automatically, e.g.:

`www.mycompany.com/blog` -> `blog.mycompany.com/blog`

`www.mycompany.com/blog/my-article` -> `blog.mycompany.com/blog/my-article`

Which is all fine, except for the fact that Wordpress shows `blog.mycompany.com` as the subdomain.

Is there any way that we can still show in the URL bar the `www` subdomain in place of `blog`?  e.g. so it still shows `www.mycompany.com/blog/my-article` ?

Is there some way we can use `mod_rewrite` or similar to alter the URL for the Wordpress site?

Comment: Something isnt right here, you couldnt pissibly be hosting a PHP application, WordPress, on an S3 bucket

Comment: Sorry - I should explained more clearly.  `www.mycompany.com` is hosted on S3 (plain HTML site), and `blog.mycompany.com` is on another server altogether that is running a LAMP stack.  What I would like is to redirect the **/blog** subfolder from my S3 site to the LAMP box without changing the `www` subdomain.

Comment: Its not possible, the DNS for a domain, or subdomain, can only point to one place. If you were to try to rewrite the blog url to the www url it would just send you back to the www site

Comment: An easier option would be: 1) To move the static site to the main server directory (www / public_html or whatever) and host it there. 2) And then I would move the WordPress instance to a sub-folder, www.example.com/blog – See this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: @CyberFerret I need to do the same thing. Did you find a workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using Cloudfront in front of S3, so in order to mix in 2 sources of content you need to

1. on your blog.mycompany.com - add rewrites of blog/* -> /* so that your blog  can handle blog.mycompany.com/blog/ urls well.
2. add new blog.mycompany.com as an Origin in "Origins and Origin Groups" tab.
3. add new "Behavior" for /blog* path pattern and point it to your newly created "blog.mycompany.com" origin.
4. if you get redirects from blog (e.g. WPMU can do that) - hack $_SERVER hostname variable in your wp-config.php and replace it

Comment: I'm doing something similar as the OP, and tried out your suggestion, @WowPress.host, and it very nearly works, except for one thing: the Cloudfront error page! for everything in the root, I need the "error page" to be /index.html (an Angular SPA; index.html is its front-controller), but it seems that when a URL within /blog/ fails, Cloudfront passes it to /index.html! how can we give 404s within /blog/ a different "error page"?

Comment: check access logs of your /blog/ server. when you call /blog/page-that-doesnt-exists - it should be present in your access log with exactly that uri. afterwards wordpress rewrites it to index.php (see you .htaccess). I guess your wp rewrites it to /index.php instead of /blog/index.php and minor modification required there in .htaccess